# Updating (seting) column herder in Ext JS

Tags: grid, extjs4.1

I have tried to set column header with these codes but they didn't work. I couldn't figure out what to do.

```
this.headerCt.setColumnHeader(2,"Surname");
grid.getColumnModel().setColumnHeader(2,"Surname");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of complicated, but here's how you do it:

```
grid.headerCt.items.items[2].setText("Surname");
```

Where 2 is the index.